# How to label the axis differently in matlab GUI of two different plots

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have created two plots on a single GUI file in matlab. I wish to label each plot as follows;
first plot: the label of x axis is position, y axis is concentration:
second plot: the label of x axis is time, y axis is concentration:
The problem is that the second plot is not getting its label

Code:

```
 C = {'k','b','r','g','y',[.5 .6 .7],[.8 .2 .6]}; % Cell array of colorss.  
phandles = plot(tott,XX(rown,:),'color',C{ind},'parent',handles.axes2);
 hold on
 xlabel('time');
 ylabel('Concentration (mol/m3)');
 title('concentration at given position vs time') axis([tott(1),tott(length(tott)),0,conc])
```

Comment: and what's the problem?

Comment: @thewaywewalk I am getting the error i.e. the second plot is not getting its label

Comment: That's not clear to me either sorry. You have 2 axes in a single GUI window is that what you mean? Also please show your code it'S going to save guesswork. Thanks!.

Comment: Could you provide a MWE so we can reproduce the error?

Comment: phandles = plot(tott,XX(rown,:),'color',C{ind},'parent',handles.axes2); % this is time versus concentration at mentioned position;
hold on
C = {'k','b','r','g','y',[.5 .6 .7],[.8 .2 .6]}; % Cell array of colros.
xlabel('time');
ylabel('Concentration (mol/m3)');
title('concentration at given position vs time')
axis([tott(1),tott(length(tott)),0,conc])
@Benoit_11

Comment: That's the code for only one of the plot. Please show all the relevant code and format it properly in your question using the `{}` symbol. thanks!

Comment: @user3355508 Can you verify [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29780328/802378)? If it's not correct, please let me know so I can clarify!

Answer (score 1):

The [xlabel article](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlabel.html#btqhkk7) shows you how to change the labels using the plot handle (in this case your `phandles`). Get the handle of your 2nd plot and use the following toy example as a reference or post your code for your second plot so I can clarify.

```
ax1 = subplot(2,1,1);
plot((1:10).^2)
xlabel(ax1,'Population')

ax2 = subplot(2,1,2);
plot((1:10).^3)
```

The variable returned when calling `subplot` is the handle for the plot. Essentially if your 2nd handle is called `phandles2`, then you can simply use:

```
xlabel(phandles2,'X Axis label for Plot 2');
ylabel(phandles2,'X Axis label for Plot 2');
```

Please post your code for your 2nd plot for a more detailed answer.